# Why does my broker have slightly different prices?

Tags: broker, online-brokerage, real-time-quotes

I took a look at the closing price of NDAQ of the day 2019 04 26

at the [NASDAQ website](https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/ndaq/real-time),

this [market data API](https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/ndaq/chart/5y),
which has excatly the same values as NASDAQ,

```
open    89.63
high    90.09
low     88.7636
close   89.86
```

and my broker XTB, inside of their so-called xStation5:

[image]
\

Comment: Is there any chance that your XTB quote is from  after hours trading which continues after regular trading ends?

Comment: That could be, yeah. But the I can't buy and sell after-hours from them as seen by the blacked out buttons and they still quote the after-hours?

Comment: I can't explain what happens across the pond.  Here, in the US, trading continues after regular hours ends at 4 PM EST.  Some brokers do not offer after hours trading and some that do   require that one be approved for it.  They might not continue providing quotes after 4 PM unless they offer that service.

Comment: I mean the quoted price is during the day seems to be mostly between the buy and sell price. Could it be just the spread of the broker?

Answer (score 1):

Becuse your broker is not a broker but a CFD bucket shop and that is HOW THEY EARN MONEY.

How much in fees do you pay? 0 - well, guess what, changing prices is where they make the money. Ups. See, "real" brokers charge all kinds of fees for every transaction and list them all separately - and are thus not allowed to modify prices.

Heck, they even say so on their website. "Share CFD trading". Buying a CFD != Buying the stock.

Comment: If XTB executes securities trades, they're a broker.  Do you know for a fact that XTB is a bucket shop or are you basing that conclusion on the question posed?

Comment: But there is NDAQ tagged as STC, and another tagged as STC CFD. They both have exactly the same buy/sell and spread, with the only difference that the non-CFD version can't be sold short.

Comment: "If XTB executes securities trades, they're a broker." - They say themselves they trade CFD, not the underlying securities.

Comment: Per Investopedia, "XTB provides access to a variety of markets such as forex, shares, indices, metals, commodities and even cryptocurrencies. The company is regulated in the UK and registered with the Financial Conduct Authority (FCA)."  It doesn't take a rocket scientist to determine that's what a broker does.